# carriage return causing cout to overwrite characters and printing out of order

Tags: c++, cout

This is a question I copied from another question that got put on hold. I am wondering why the extra hyphen is being added to the beginning of the output buffer stream when I concatenate more than one string in `cout`, and why it is overwriting a character there?

Below is a minimal example showing how printing any string causes this to happen. I posted this question before but it was put on hold due to lack of reproducibility. The reason it wasn't reproducible is because when I copied the text file I wasn't copying hidden characters. It turns out when I did `cat -e ex.txt`, the lines were all ending with `^M` for some reason. This is the cause of the problem. answering it below.

-Paul

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    string str;
    getline(infile, str);
    cout<<"str: "<<str<<"-"<<endl;
}
```

I compile and run the code with:

```
g++ -o hw4.exe prog4.cpp

./hw4.exe ex2.txt

$ cat -e ex2.txt
Bella Abzug ^M$
```

And below is the output of

```
od -x ex2.txt

0000000 6542 6c6c 2061 6241 757a 2067 0a0d
0000016
```

The output:

```
-tr: Bella Abzug
```

But I still do not know WHY this is the case. Why would a carriage return followed by a line ending cause this behavior?

Comment: Kids these days. Don't even know what a teletype is. <g> A carriage return moves the output position to the start of the current line. And just for completeness, a linefeed moves the output position down by one line. The combination moves the output position to the start of the next line. That's why Windows files use CR + LF to mark the start a new line.

Comment: But the same thing happens when I have '^M$'. Working on a reproducible example now

Comment: `'\n'` is a "new-line character" in the C family of languages. When literal text that contains `'\n'` is written to an output stream it tells the runtime support to do whatever is needed to start a new line. That's a contract between the runtime support and the compiler; whatever value they agree on is represented in program text as `'\n'`. That's often the same **value** as the ASCII representation for newline, but it's not an ASCII code.

Comment: I didn't mention originally because I didn't see the relevance at first, but there is in fact a newline '$' character after my '^M'. See above edits. For some reason it is not recognizing the newline in cout. But the strange thing is that it is being recognized by other functions, such as getline() in fstream -- it is correctly identify line endings, but cout is not.

Comment: The $ in `^M$` is not part of ex2.txt; It's the prompt. It shows the cursor is not moved to the next line by `cat ex2.txt`. The C++ program never processed a $ character.

Comment: You're right that it never processed the character, and I will update accordingly. But it isn't the prompt -- it's because cat -e outputs $ for line endings. will update the question as soon as I figure out what that character actually is

Comment: "This is a question I copied from another question that got put on hold." -- Can you link to that question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

^M is `carriage return`, ie 'move cursor to start of line'

Comment: so why is it not recognizing the "$" after the carriage return as a newline?

Comment: Because the C family of languages does not treat `'$'` as any kind of control character. It's a normal character that represents `'$'`. Nothing more.

Comment: but then why does fstream recognize it when I call newline? Let me know if you would like another example of that.

Comment: no part of c/c++ io treats '$' as meaning anything special. Maybe you are asking, 'where did the $ character go? and why didnt I end up on a new line'. Answer, once you start outputing control characters without meaning to allsorts of add things happen

Comment: The line-feed has been removed by `getline`, but not the carriage-return.

Comment: the above two comments appear in conflict with one another. so does fstream remove '$' because it is a special character?

Comment: By the way I am running this in Cygwin

Comment: nobody treats $ as a special character ever, anywhere. The same thing will happen with '!' instead without without the ^M

Comment: Ok here is the issue: "$" is the character used to denote a new line when you use the "cat -e" command. I am not sure what this hidden character actually is. How can I find out? And then the question still remains of why, for whatever character it actually is, newline recognizes it but does not recognize ^M

Comment: use `od -x` rather than cat to see the actual contents of a file - this is what I think u are getting at

Comment: it actually sounds like you have a DOS file (which has crlf at then end of each line) as opposed to a unix file which only has lf. use dos2unix to convert it

Comment: ok, I posted the output of `od -x` in an edit above. yes that may be the answer.

Comment: yes, that was indeed the issue. If you could write up an answer I will accept

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is too late, but for future record I just leave my answer.

I went trough the same issue and it seems that if the *.txt has not been created as binary the overwrite happens.

If the ***.txt** has been **created as binary**, the overwrite **does not happen**.

Maybe it is the same issue for some of you.

Best regards